# Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped. Eclipse / Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-virtual-device

I'm new to eclipse and wanted to know how to keep this message

```
Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped."
```

from showing every time I run my Test Application in my AVD. I'm trying to make a LineView Layout and Eclipse shows no mistakes. So how can I fix this and how can I find out what the problem is if Eclipse shows no problems?

(Here's a copy of my Logcat)

```
05-29 23:49:12.604: D/AndroidRuntime(832): Shutting down VM
05-29 23:49:12.675: W/dalvikvm(832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{testing.android.application.three/testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity" on path: /data/app/testing.android.application.three-1.apk
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity" on path: /data/app/testing.android.application.three-1.apk
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-29 23:49:12.775: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  ... 11 more
05-29 23:49:30.595: E/Trace(851): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-29 23:49:30.965: D/AndroidRuntime(851): Shutting down VM
05-29 23:49:31.015: W/dalvikvm(851): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{testing.android.application.three/testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity" on path: /data/app/testing.android.application.three-1.apk
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity" on path: /data/app/testing.android.application.three-1.apk
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-29 23:49:31.075: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 11 more
05-29 23:49:35.207: I/Process(851): Sending signal. PID: 851 SIG: 9
```

(Here's a copy of my activity_main_activity_three.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityThree" >
</LinearLayout>
```

(Here's a copy of my MainActivityThree.java)

```
package testing.android.application.three;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivityThree extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_three);
        String[] names = new String[]{"Text 1","Text 2","Text 3","Text 4","Text 5","Text"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test 1" + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

(Here's a copy of my ThreeManifest)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="testing.android.application.three"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/AppName"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/ThreeTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity"
            android:label="@string/AppName" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what does LogCat tell ?

Comment: I could not find any error on the code. And when I ran the code, it worked. When exactly do the error occur? What is the configuration of your AVD?

Comment: @igor.araujo I'm using the nexus 4 as my AVD. Even in my Graphical Layout it stays blank, why?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I posted a copy of my Logcat running my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your LogCat and your manifest, you can see that the name of your activity class is different from the name of the class that is presented inside the manifest file.

So, in order to fix the problem, change this line in your manifest

```
android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity"
```

for

```
android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree"
```

This may solve the problem!

Always keep in mind that the AndroidManifest file "governs" your application. Every service and activity you want to use or every permission you need for your application, you'll have to register it inside your manifest file and do it correctly, otherwise, you'll experience crashes like that.

Comment: Thanks friend, I got the application to start but still the Graphic Layout stays the same (Blank).

Comment: @igot.araujo Graphic Layout stays the same IN ECLIPSE (Blank). In the emulator it shows it like it should look. I just wanted to make this clear.

Comment: This is expected since your layout is empty (actually it has one LinearLayout, but it is empty). If you place a TextView inside the layout, it will appear inside the graphic layout.
i.e: 
<LinearLayout ...>
   <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Hello World!"/>
</LinearLayout>

But the bottom line is: you are not even using the layout. Your activity is a ListActivity that populates itself automatically, using an adapter. You are actually using a default android layout called android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: Take a look at the [ListActivity Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). See if you understand how does it work. In this page, they explain how to use a custom layout for the ListActivity. As I said, for now, you're just using the default layout.